# Как сделать такие кривые и градиент на картинках?

Tags: css

Есть с виду простая картинка. Но для меня сложно ее сверстать.
[image: кривые безье и градиент]
как

1. как сделать градиент поверх картинок
2. как добавить эти линии?

Comment: А вы уверены, что это не одно изображение?

Comment: Верстка должна быть резиновой? Адаптивной? Если нет - я бы посоветовал вставить это картинкой с `width: 100%`. Можно даже svg.

Comment: верстка да, должна быть резиновой. Верстаю по сетке бутстрап.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю нет смысла верстать кривые, это не оправданно, можете почитать про SVG и сделать их на SVG, либо вы можете сделать отдельно круги с иконками и бекграундом сделать линии, это будет наиболее оптимальный вариант, сэкономит время и усилия. 
Градиент делается очень просто, например у вас есть родительский контейнер в котором лежит иконка авто, в этот же контейнер добавьте еще один элемент с классом .overlay с парметром background-image: linear-gradient

```css
.vehicle__layer {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}
.vehicle__layer::after {
 content: 'your icon';
 font-size: 20px;
 color: black;
 margin: auto;
}
.vehicle__layer__overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 30%, #000 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='vehicle__layer'>
  <div class='vehicle__layer__overlay'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Беда в том, что градиент должен ложиться на 4 иконки, без заливки. То что это должен быть дополнительный слой, я понимал и сам. Вчера делал подобное для текста. Теперь вот нужно для картинок. Но пока не получается. А кривые я непрочь через SVG, только че то не могу найти инфу - как перегнать из фотошопа в данный формат (

Comment: Можно глянуть скрин с заливкой? Я раньше перегонял через illustrator.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znZlmDYOPaA     попробуйте запрос convert psd to svg, или что-то в этом роде, инфы хватало раньше. Я бы  остановился на варианте с бекграундом. меньше возни. Смотря какие задачи, если это просто статичные картинки с каким-то ховером тогда смысл там городить, даже если делать респонсив то на определенном разрешении я бы эти иконки скинул в колонку и естествено поставил бы бекграунд в дисплей нон.

Comment: По градиенту понял, сделайте каждую иконку тем цветом которого она является. Там не явный градиент, каждая иконка меняется в градации целиком. Я думал что градиент явный.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> как добавить эти линии?
> ```

Как вариант, сделайте их фоновой картинкой, как было сказано в комментариях.

> ```
> как сделать градиент поверх картинок
> ```

Не усложняйте задачу. В данном случае видно, что градиента на самих картинках нет, поэтому просто пипеткой узнайте цвета данных четырёх картинок и вручную задайте им эти цвета, вот и всё.