# Как верстаются такие линии?

Tags: html, css, svg

Можно наложить `background`-ом и потом абсолютное позиционирование, либо есть другой, быстрый и правильный метод?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SVG - самый внятный вариант

Comment: хорошо, а элементы как спозиционировать посоветуете ?

Comment: Тоже `SVG`...   так как `css-ом`   добиться такого и качества и результата, если только на каждый пиксель прописывать медиа

Comment: ну на счет линий думаю лучше свг, но сами блоки то верстаются как обычно, просто как их спозиционировать так же строго по линии?

Comment: Я же сказал....  `SVG`...  по другому ни как....

Comment: а есть какой нибудь пример?)

Comment: @Air ничего не надо в медиа прописывать, если держать соотношение сторон картинки. Тогда позиция в процентах, и все. А сообщение сторон держать - пара правил в css

Comment: @KAGGDesign, я прекрасно знаю что нужно, что бы реализовать на `css`, но я  бы на `css` не стал бы такого делать... мороки больше....

Comment: @Air ну и где тут морока? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708192/220220

Comment: @KAGGDesign,  ну в твоем примере, все красиво, а тут ему надо поддерживать и позиции и размеры  блоков ...  я же не говорю, что не возможно или в место 20 минут уйдет на это неделя...  Я просто высказываю свое мнение, что SVG лучше...

Comment: @Air может, и лучше, но поддерживать позиции и размеры на css - не проблема вообще. Все в процентах.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ты тоже верно говоришь... Мое мнение исходит из того, что у него и фоновой картинки нет.... Если уж полоску рисовать в SVG,  та почему бы   блоки сразу там же не выставить и закончить??

Comment: @user281117, я  отписался человеку, нашему гуру SVG, жди он тебе скоро ответит....)))

Comment: @user281117 у вас есть картинка фона одной кривой без прямоугольников? Если нет, то свяжитесь со своим дизайнером и попросите его переслать требуемую картинку. Я думаю это будет не трудно для него сохранить соответствующий слой. Если конечно он сам рисовал, а не позаимствовал где-нибудь. Имея такую картинку задача будет решена, хоть в css, но лучше в svg

Comment: Такие вопросы были один миллион раз...

Comment: @Duoxx, приведи пожалуйста подобный вопрос, буду признателен

Comment: @Arthur например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570270/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/570293

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-css/726071

Comment: @Duoxx, в принципе они все между собой похожи, но не до конца=)

Comment: @Arthur принцип однинаков

Comment: @Duoxx, думаю этот вопрос закрыли бы, если бы явно был виден дубликат

Comment: @user281117 добавлен вариант адаптивного решения, работающий во всех браузерах https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826785/28748

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Если вам нужно получить полностью адаптивный график, который работает во всех браузерах, включая `IE`,  то конечно нужно использовать SVG.**

Идеальный вариант, когда дизайнер даёт исходные данные в векторном формате, но если это растровая картинка, то можно воспользоваться следующей техникой:

- Загружаем растровую картинку в векторный редактор с помощью
  нескольких строчек svg.  Это нужно, чтобы точно позиционировать
  положение векторных элементов относительно растрового фона.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="441" height="495" viewBox="0 0 441 495" > 
     <image xlink:href="SlalomTransp2.png" width="441" height="495" />
</svg>
```

- Нам необходимо получить формулу `path` которая точно повторяет форму
  кривой на растровом изображении.  Для этого в векторном редакторе с
  помощью инструмента - `"рисовать кривые Безье"` добавляем узловые точки
  вдоль кривой и двигая рычагами узловых точек, добиваемся точного совпадения нашего path с кривой на растровой картинке.
- Сохраняем файл и копируем из него формулу `path` кривой.
- Далее создаем заготовки баннеров  и помещаем их в секцию
  `<defs>` для  дальнейшего многократного использования
- Вызываем баннер из хранилища и позиционируем его относительно кривой:

`<use xlink:href="#banner" x="50" y="14" />`

- Размещаем текст в баннере

`<text x="58" y="25" >Ноябрь 2017</text>`

.**Такая техника может быть освоена  начинающими изучение SVG.**
Она немного трудоемка, но дает неоспоримые преимущества перед `CSS`

1. Кривые в `CSS` `offset-path` поддерживает только экспериментальная технология `Chrome`
   В svg кривые поддерживают все современный браузеры плюс`IE`.
2. Если будет необходимость, то легко заменить одну форму баннера на другую.
3. Можно менять форму кривой, без нарушения верстки.
4. Приложение полностью адаптивно и верстка никогда не сломается при изменении размера дисплея гаджета.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 441 495" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  

<defs>
<g id="banner">
<rect width="70" height="40" fill="#26365F"/> 
<polyline points="35,40 35,58" stroke="#45678B" stroke-width="1.5"/> 
<circle cx="35" cy="60" r="3" fill="none" stroke="#45678B" stroke-width="2"/>
</g>
<g id="banner2">
<polyline points="50,50 50,75" stroke="#45678B" stroke-width="1.5"/> 
<circle cx="50" cy="75" r="3" fill="none" stroke="#45678B" stroke-width="2"/>
<rect width="100" height="60" fill="#26365F"/> 
</g>
</defs>

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#182037" />
<path fill="none" stroke="#45678B" stroke-width="1" d="m82.7 74c0 0 27.9-4.1 41.9-5.5 15.8-1.6 31.6-2.5 47.4-3.3 13.9-0.7 27.9-1.1 41.9-1.1 15.1 0 30.2 0.1 45.2 1.2 12.2 0.9 24.3 2.3 36.3 4.4 13 2.3 25.9 5 38.6 8.8 10.9 3.3 22.7 5.6 32 12.1 7.9 5.6 15.8 12.9 18.7 22 3 9.1 1.5 19.8-2.2 28.7-3.9 9.4-11.7 17.1-19.8 23.1-9.6 7.1-21.6 10.6-33 14.4-15.4 5.1-31.4 8.5-47.5 11-13.1 2-26.4 2.2-39.7 3.3-19.1 1.5-38.2 2.6-57.3 4.4-16.9 1.6-34 2.6-50.7 5.5-6.7 1.2-13.6 2.3-20 4.8-9.3 3.6-19.5 6-26.2 14.4-4.9 6.2-7.7 14.8-6.8 22.7 0.9 7.6 6.2 14.4 11.5 20 5.7 6 13.4 9.7 20.8 13.3 7.6 3.7 15.9 6.1 24 8.6 8.3 2.6 16.8 4.6 25.3 6.6 8.8 2.1 17.6 3.8 26.5 5.6 9.9 1.9 19.8 3.7 29.8 5.5 12.3 2.1 24.6 4.4 36.9 6.1 13 1.9 26.1 3.3 39.2 4.9 12.9 1.6 26 1.6 38.6 4.8 12.3 3.1 25.9 5.4 35.3 14 5.4 5 9.1 12.5 9.9 19.8 1.1 9.4-1 19.9-6.6 27.6-5.8 8-16.2 11.7-25.3 15.4-11.9 4.9-24.9 6.1-37.5 8.8-13.2 2.8-26.5 5.1-39.7 7.7-12.5 2.5-25.1 4.8-37.5 7.7-13 3.1-25.8 6.6-38.6 10.4-11.9 3.6-24 6.5-35.3 11.6-10.5 4.8-20.2 11.1-29.8 17.6-5.9 4-11.4 8.5-16.9 13.1-4 3.4-8.3 6.6-11.8 10.6-0.4 0.5-1.1 1.6-1.1 1.6" />

<use xlink:href="#banner" x="50" y="14" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="175" y="4" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="300" y="18" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="351" y="65" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="300" y="117" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="210" y="133" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="100" y="143" />
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="48" y="191" />
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="118" y="231" />
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="198" y="248" />
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="278" y="258" />
<use xlink:href="#banner" x="344" y="308" />
<use xlink:href="#banner2" x="200" y="343" /> 
<use xlink:href="#banner2" x="50" y="407" /> 
 
<g font-size="10" fill="#F0F0F0">
<text x="58" y="25" >Ноябрь 2017</text> 
<text x="53" y="40" >Запуск проекта</text>
<text x="182" y="15" >Декабрь 2017</text> 
<text x="186" y="30" >Инвестиции</text>
<text x="309" y="30" >Январь 2018</text> 
<text x="357" y="77" >Февраль 2018</text>
<text x="312" y="130" >Март 2018</text>
<text x="215" y="144" >Апрель 2018</text>
<text x="115" y="155" >Май 2018</text> 
<text x="60" y="215" >Июнь 2018</text> 
<text x="130" y="255" >Июль 2018</text>
<text x="208" y="270" >Август 2018</text>
<text x="281" y="280" >Сентябрь 2018</text> 
<text x="350" y="330" >Октябрь 2018</text>
<text x="225" y="365" >Ноябрь 2018</text>
<text x="201" y="385" >Окончательный выбор </text>
<text x="67" y="425" >Декабрь 2018 </text>
<text x="57" y="445" >Финишные работы </text>



</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS - он в изначально "заквадраченный", рисует прямые линии и прямоугольники. Можно скругляться углы и получать из бордеров изогнутые линии - но в этом именно случае извращаться не стоит.

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #172238;
}
.timeline__back {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.timeline__info {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.timeline__item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #1e2b4b;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
.timeline__item:before,
.timeline__item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
.timeline__item:before {
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #52789c;
}
.timeline__item:after {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 -4px;
  background-color: #172238;
  border: 1px solid #52789c;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.timeline__item strong {
  display: block;
}
.timeline__item--01 {
  top: 49%;
  left: 50%;
}
.timeline__item--02 {
  top: 33%;
  left: 80%;
}
.timeline__item--03 {
  top: 75%;
  left: 24%;
}
```

```html
<section class="timeline">
  <img class="timeline__back" src="http://war.webdrafts.ru/bg_line.svg">
  <ul class="timeline__info">
    <li class="timeline__item timeline__item--01">
      <strong>Январь 2017</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    </li>
    <li class="timeline__item timeline__item--02">
      <strong>Январь 2017</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit magnam, numquam
    </li>
    <li class="timeline__item timeline__item--03">
      <strong>Январь 2017</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**Сделайте так:**

0) Делаем div-враппер, позишн = релатив, фон - синий.

1) В него кладем именно картинкой (не фоном) кривую линию - в .svg (дисплей = блок, ширина = 100%, высота = авто) Почему не фоном? потому что картинка будет распирать враппер по ширине и задавать высоту, будет удобно "резиниться".

2) Также добавляете во враппер список ul (позишн = статик) и в него - уже li (позишн = абсолют) с текстами. У каждого li будет два класса - первый, пусть .timeline__item (ширина, рамка, фон, цвет текста - один для всех li), и второй, который у всех разный - отвечает за положение каждого во враппере .timeline__item--01 (left: 22.7%; top: 45%;). Позицию в процентах, если резинить нужно.

**Не нужно тексты пихать в картинку svg - они могут быть проигнорированы поисковиками!**

**Что в итоге?**

1. Картинка в фоне задает размер для враппера, в ней кривая линия, несвойственная для css.
2. В коде - четкий список с данными в виде списка, seo - одобряэ )
3. На экране - всё расставлено как нужно. Кружочек делаем через .timeline__item:before, вертикальную черту от блока к нему - .timeline__item:after

Проверить резиновость на https://codepen.io/Valiev/pen/LmmjgL

Comment: Я считаю, что лучше давать разработчику общее направление мыслей, а не конкретное решение для копипаста. Если svg внедрен в html как код - тогда да, а если как картинка - никакой индексации не будет. А уже если внедрять текст в код - то в нормальные html-теги.
Как-то так.

Comment: Ну, надеюсь мой ответ всё-таки пригодится! )
PS - К стати, анимация svg-улитки классно получилась, положил себе в избранное, на выходных разберу подход, спасибо за полноту ответа там!

Comment: Ну чтож, останемся каждый при своем )
Если есть время и желание выдавать готовые решения с точностью до точки с запятой - я не против! )

Comment: нормально и даже хорошо, Вы положительно удивили меня. Жаль, что истинной адаптивности, которую дает SVG нет Картинки транспарантов при уменьшении окна браузера наезжают друг на друга Но автора вопроса наверное итак устроит (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну такая истинная адаптивность что бы и на супер-мелких экранах работало это уже работать и весьма тяжёлая самого автора, думаю это уже к теме вопроса не относится. А может для мелких экранов просто другую страницу проще сделать без кривой линии просто с вертикальной прямой... думаю это было бы лучшим решением.

Comment: Да, абзацу устарел, убрал его. Адаптивность не делал, просто "резину". Это хороший, крепкий кроссбраузерный вариант.
На мелких экранах по-моему уже стоит просто в столбик этот таймлайн перестраивать.

Answer (score 3):

CSS свойство `offset-path` - путь кривой, по которой располагаются элементы (SVG-формат), `offset-distance` - расстояние от начала кривой в процентах.
Если нужно блоки выровнять горизонтально - в руки Вам геометрия, JS и `transform-rotate` )))

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0 4em;
  width: 100%;
}

svg, .box {
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  offset-path: path("M0,380 C9.32293455,260.130586 35.1510596,182.38319 77.484375,146.757812 C140.984348,93.3197459 266.91385,262.809311 332.683594,240.753906 C398.453337,218.698502 450.023437,1.28465307 450.023437,1.28465307");
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
    offset-distance:15%;
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
    offset-distance:50%;
}

.three {
    background-color: blue;
    offset-distance:78%;
}
```

```html
<svg class="track" viewBox="0 0 451 379" width="451px" height="379px">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" d="M0,380 C9.32293455,260.130586 35.1510596,182.38319 77.484375,146.757812 C140.984348,93.3197459 266.91385,262.809311 332.683594,240.753906 C398.453337,218.698502 450.023437,1.28465307 450.023437,1.28465307"></path>
</svg>

<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box three"></div>
```

Comment: Крутое решение, не знал об offset-path, лови плюс=)

Comment: Только вот незадача, без адаптивности это работает корректно=))

Comment: @Arthur, по моему это адаптивное решение. path ведь можно подстроить под людой экран

Comment: Убери width & height из svg и попробуй, почему-то смещаются квадраты

Comment: @Arthur, согласен. Не адаптивно совсем)

Comment: @Areshka и ещё один неприятный сюрприз offset-path экспериментальная технология Chrome уже 3 год внедряют, но работает только в Chrome и больше нигде  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path

Comment: Грустно, да? https://caniuse.com/#search=offset-distance

Comment: Жаль, что это версия только для хрома

Comment: @MaxWall, я же писал, что поддержка слабая. Думаете я не смотрел?